# Incorrect usage of WITH ROLLUP and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, database, rollup

I try to import sql file to MySql database but I run into a problem:

```
ERROR 1221 (HY000) at line 4598: Incorrect usage of WITH ROLLUP and DISTINCT

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_employees_rollup`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_employees_rollup` ()
BEGIN
SELECT Distinct City ,Sum(Salary) Salary_By_City FROM employees
GROUP BY City WITH ROLLUP;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `DISTINCT City` in a `GROUP BY` query because because each record in the result set will already be distinct.  Use this query instead:

```
SELECT City,
       SUM(Salary) Salary_By_City
FROM employees
GROUP BY City WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: thats what I thought but I wasn't sure. Thanks.